# How to use a property file in an OSGi bundle

Tags: java, file-io, properties, osgi

In an OSGi bundle in my application I have a property file included named `ontologymapping.properties`.
Now I want to read the content of this property file.
In some example code I found something like this in the start method of the bundle:

```
public void startObservationAdapter(BundleContext context) {
    String filename = context.getProperty("ontologymapping.properties");
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        ontologymapping.load(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where `ontologymapping` is a Properties instance.
When I run this code the JVM can't find the file.
I guess the reason is that the file isn't included in the BundleContext.
How can I do that? Or what is another way to read the contents of the property file?
The bundle is not declarative, it's an api bundle for another one which is declarative.

Comment: context.getProperty does not do what you think it does. Also: Which bundle is the file "ontologymapping.properties" and which bundle has this code?

That said, why no http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.
The problem was that the ontologymapper.properties was located in a bundle where an abstract class was defined.
In that abstract class the start method of the extending classes was implemented and in that start method I called context.getBundle().
This seems to return the bundle of the implementing classes and not the bundle with the abstract class.
So the problem was fixed with placing the properties file in the bundles with implementing classes.

Answer (score 4):

I think you got a few wires crossed. context.getProperty(..) is similar to System.getProperty(...), and actually you find most of System.getProperties() in the context. So in your case, and your code seems to do this, you can put a file name in the system properties with the VM -D command line option: -Dontologymapping.properties="myfile.properties". This should make your code work.

However ... the problem with this type of code is you now have a bundle that needs to read a file on a file system. There are three cases to distinguish:

1. ontologymapping.properties is user specific and small
2. ontologymapping.properties is user specific and large (i.e. the properties are a cheap GUI for you code)
3. ontologymapping.properties is just a convenient way for the programmer to store its data

In case 1 you might want to look at Configuration Admin with Metatype. This allows you to create apps with a nice configuration GUI. Using the bnd DS annotations you can get away with awfully little code and a really nice gui in Apache Felix Webconsole.

In case 2, your code above is valid. you could think of adding a gogo shell and create a command so people can read and update it.

In the last case, #3, you should store the properties inside the bundle and read it with Myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/ontology.properties"). In bnd(tools), just `Include-Resource: ontolology.properties` and it will be present in your bundle, ready to be read.

Comment: The third case is exactly what I need. However, I don't understand what you mean with bnd(tools)? Do you mean I have to put `Include-Resource: ontologymapping.properties` in my MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: bnd(tools): bnd is a library to create manifests from a 'bnd' file. It is used in the Apache Felix Maven bundle plugin and in an Eclipse IDE called bndtools: http://bndtools.org/ It is by far the best way to make bundles. If you do not want to use bnd, you have to make sure the ontologymapping.properties file is in your resources. Either through maven or via your jar command.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL of your properties file with bundle.getResource('mypropfile.properties') where bundle is the one that contains the properties file. Based on the URL you can get the inputStream of the file (resourceURL.openStream). You can pass the inputstream to properties.load function.

In case you do not want to use OSGi specific code or you cannot get the bundle object of the bundle that contains the properties file you can play with the classloaders. Imagine MyClass is in the same bundle as the properties file. In this case the following code snippet works as well:

```
Properties myProps = new Properties();
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("ontologymapping.properties");
  myProps.load(is);
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the OSGi way of doing it. When I run it now, he still doesn't find the properties file though. I still get a NullPointerException. The properties file is located in the bundle itself, where this code is written. Do I have to register the file as a resource somewhere perhaps?

Comment: No. You can access any file in the bundle with bundle.getResource. In your code if you call context.getBundle().getResource("ontologymapping.properties") should give back an URL that points to your properties file and you should be able to open an InputStream with that URL. If the file is there and you are sure that the context points to your bundle you should try starting the resource path with a slash like "/ontologymapping.properties". You can also have problems if the bundle is only in installed state but I do not think that is your case.

Comment: The method call `context.getBundle().getResource("ontologymapping.properties")` returns `null` and the file is in the directory, I tried using the "/" but that didn't work neither, how can I check if the `context.getBundle()` returns my bundle?